# Can I create a has_one association in a single call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Item which I split the table with cache_item. CachItem contains some serialized fragments. Like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cache_item
end

class CacheItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

how would I tell it to create one and save it automatically?

I do something like this:

```
if !cache_item
  CacheItem.create! item_id: id
  self.reload # seems like I shouldn't have to do this
end
```

but seems like there should be a single call. Is there?

For a has_many, I can do:

```
>item.comments.count
>1
>item.comments.create! # inserts with proper information
>2
```

What is the pattern for a has_one?

Comment: `item.cache_item.create` you can do like this

Comment: I get create being called on nil which is erroring out. I thought your soln should work though

Comment: You should do `CacheItem.create_item!`, with this you don't need to reload!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `has_one` association, you can use `create_association!` as documented: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

In your case

```
item.create_cached_item!
```

Answer (score 1):

For an Item that has_many Comment(s) you use:

```
Item.comments.create()
```

And for an Item that has_one Comment you use:

```
Item.create_comment
```